# Combining two pandas dataframes without including duplicates?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have two dataframes that I want to combine ***without creating duplicate rows***, the column labels remain the same for both dataframes and `date` is set as the index for both.

`df1`:

```
date                 A   B        C
2020-02-21 16:00:00  10  32.0000  23   
2020-02-21 15:59:00  23  11.2100  10   
2020-02-21 15:58:00  82  38.2350  18
```

*and*

`df2`:

```
date                 A   B        C
2020-02-21 15:59:00  23  11.2100  10   
2020-02-21 15:58:00  82  38.2350  18   
2020-02-21 15:57:00  32  22.2900  76
```

*This is the desired result:*

```
date                 A   B        C
2020-02-21 16:00:00  10  32.0000  23   
2020-02-21 15:59:00  23  11.2100  10   
2020-02-21 15:58:00  82  38.2350  18   
2020-02-21 15:57:00  32  22.2900  76
```

How should I do this (with pandas)?

Comment: Hi, Duplicates on A column only, or duplicate on all the column data?

Comment: Share the code you worked on?

Comment: I don't want any *rows* duplicated as a whole. The data is stock market data, so the columns won't ever be different based on the date if that makes sense

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure if there is a more elegant solution, but you could concatenate the dataframes first with the duplicates then drop them afterwards.

```
output = pd.concat([df1, df2]).drop_duplicates()
```

pd.concat: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.concat.html

drop_duplicates: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.drop_duplicates.html

Comment: This seems to work great. I assume this checks every column for each row to drop duplicates. Is there a way you know of that I could have it just check if the index is a duplicate?

Comment: @JeffoJam You are right. You can use the subset attribute to do that. 
Assuming date is your index, 

output = pd.concat([df1, df2]).drop_duplicates(subset='date')

Comment: I did try that and double checked that my index is indeed set to `'date'` but it returned:


`raise KeyError(diff)`

`KeyError: Index(['date'], dtype='object')`

Comment: By ``` ```, you mean it returned nothing? Maybe you can update your question with your dataframes and new code so I can have a better look.